# gradle uploading some files (not artifacts) to webdav

Tags: gradle, webdav

I'm working on a project which uses Gradle which is I'm not familiar with.

Can anybody please tell how can I upload files (`not artifacts` but files such as `build/doc/javadoc`) to a WebDAV?